# Is it worth flagging a question as an exact duplicate when others have already cast close as exact dupe votes on it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, flags

I don't have close vote rights on MSO yet, but since I do on regular SO, I am familiar with how the close votes work.  I can tell when there's an auto-generated close vote comment that looks like "Possible duplicate of <link>" that there's been a close vote cast for this question with that as the proposed exact duplicate.

I also know that when I flag a question I can choose "does not belong here" and essentially "cast a close vote" as well, but with a flag instead of a close vote.  Since my name doesn't show up in the "Closed as" list after this question is closed, I assume it doesn't really translate to a "close vote" even if the flag is accepted.

So my question is - if someone with the right privileges has already cast a close vote on a given question, is it even worth flagging the post with my not-really-a-close-vote flag?  Does it just fill up the mod queue unnecessarily?

Comment: There is a recent change such that if you do have close votes, it will auto-convert your flag to a vote. If not, or it is not a close vote-able category, you get to do more in the flag UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you spot that the comment was added some time ago (i.e. more than a day or two ago) then it would be worth flagging the post. Usually if enough 10K users see the post on the tools pages it will get closed quite quickly (assuming it should be closed of course). Therefore, a post that's still open with this comment might not be getting the views necessary. Flagging it get another set of eyes on the post and action one way or another.

If the comment was added quite recently then it's probably not worth it.

Of course this assumes you're talking about Stack Overflow. For the other sites where there are fewer users with close rights and even fewer with access to the tools pages it's always useful to flag it.

Comment: Yeah in particular I'm asking about here on MSO because I *can* cast close votes on SO, but these are good ideas and good feedback in general, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel, this isn't MSO anymore :P

Answer (score 5):

I would say any time you feel *strongly* about a close, you should mod flag it -- regardless of how many close votes it has already.

Perhaps more pragmatically, you should weight your close mod flags towards questions that might otherwise be "off the beaten path" and not getting enough attention.

(It's worth pointing out that we recently upped close votes per day from 12 to 24, so you do have more close votes and should try to use those first when applicable..)

Comment: I'd love me some more close votes. I still see 12 myself on SO. When will we see this deployed?

Comment: @michael dang, I'm glad you said that -- the site-override was still present at the old default level (it should have been blank). It's fixed now.

Comment: I'm not sure who this Michael Dang character is, but I see the votes now. Thanks :)

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow also seems to have this issue of not getting the 24 votes, unlike the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites.

Comment: @grace thanks, I changed it there too.

Comment: This recommendation has [apparently been superseded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185926/) ([see also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181020/)), largely due to the existence of the close vote review queue.