# Allow to flag a question for closure without casting a vote if I'm out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

**This is not a duplicate of [I'm out of close votes. Can I use moderator flags instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185926/im-out-of-close-votes-can-i-use-my-flags) because that is a support question asking if one can use *moderator attention* flags to indicate that questions should be closed. This is a feature request asking for the ability to use *recommend closure* flags (which feed questions into close review, and don't go to moderators) when one is out of close votes.**

Currently, flagging for closure [is treated the same as casting a close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263549/174091) for users with the [vote-to-close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). From what I can see, this is basically for users' convenience - if I think the question should be closed, there's hardly ever a reason not to cast a vote if I can.

I cannot see however why I cannot still use a *flag* to nominate the question for close review - since this *won't include casting a vote* - same as if I didn't have the privilege.

This goes for all close reasons, including [suggesting a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253970/allow-marking-questions-as-duplicate-even-when-out-of-close-votes).

If a vote *creates* a review item, why not consume *both* a flag and a vote? This will mitigate the cumulative effect referred to in 
[Robert Longson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276647/allow-to-flag-a-question-for-closure-without-casting-a-vote-if-im-out-of-close/276663#276663) and is quite logical: flags are used to create review items while votes to vote on them.

It's also very strange that users with <3,000 reputation can add *dozens*, if not *up to 100*, questions to the close vote queue (provided their flagging history is excellent, and this number can increase quickly since a single close vote results in the flag being marked helpful), but when a user earns 3,000 rep, they're all of a sudden limited to adding only 24 questions to the queue.

Related discussions:

- [I'm out of close votes. Can I use moderator flags instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185926/im-out-of-close-votes-can-i-use-my-flags) (considered flagging for moderator attention instead which is obviously a no-go)
- [Allow marking questions as duplicate even when out of close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253970/allow-marking-questions-as-duplicate-even-when-out-of-close-votes)
- [Should flagging a question for closure prevent close-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting)
- [Allow me to flag to close even if I already used my close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258721/allow-me-to-flag-to-close-even-if-i-already-used-my-close-vote)

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but there seems to be a general trend toward cutting off lower-level privileges if a new privilege is gained that is more powerful in the same area. See also the pushback against allowing mods to forgo their binding votes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy could you link to the "pushback" discussion you're referring to? Because I've had such a suggestion on my mind for some time, too!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-close-open-vote especially.

Comment: I edited the title of the other question to make it clearer that they meant mod flags. If you just read the title it looked like a dupe.

Answer (score 7):

It is not mentioned in the question, but this becomes really important for reviewing First Posts (or the new First Questions) or Triage queues when out of close votes.

I was reviewing a first question which needed to be closed. As I am out of close votes, I was basically forced to skip (as "No action needed" is not applicable). This means I have to hope that the next user encountering this item will make the *"right"* action.

Instead, if I could just *flag* it for closure, without even casting an actual close vote, at least I can finish the review with the **appropriate** action, and know that it now made its way to the close votes review queue with just one less vote than it will otherwise have.