# Allow to automatically add the duplicate-suggestion comment, even when out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

This is *almost* a duplicate of [Allow to flag a question for closure without casting a vote if I'm out of close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276647/allow-to-flag-a-question-for-closure-without-casting-a-vote-if-im-out-of-close) in the sense that if that is implemented, then of course it would be best to flag as a duplicate along with the comment. I don't think *it is* a duplicate, because even if the above is declined, it can still be nice to at least have the comment added, even if the question is not flagged.

---

When voting to close (or flagging) a question as a duplicate, an automatic comment is added for you, formatted as *"Does this answer your question? <link to question>"*.

When out of close votes and trying to close as duplicate, you simply get the *"daily close vote reached"* message and no comment is added.

I would like to suggest that the comment be added anyway, even if you're not actually voting to close. This will obviously help the OP by still directing them to the suggested duplicate, and make it easier for other users to actually apply the duplicate as a close vote.

I know, you can just copy the link and format it into a comment. But it happens to me that I forget I'm actually out of votes and try to close out of habit. It would be nice if the comment will just be added.

Comment: You know you can manually add a similar/identical comment yourself, right?

Comment: @Makyen from the question: *"I know, you can just copy the link and format it into a comment. But it happens to me that I forget I'm actually out of votes and try to close out of habit. It would be nice if the comment will just be added."* Also it's alot of work :)